# Convert ipv4 and ipv6 addresses to Integer

Tags: mysql, sql, linux

I am trying to convert multiple ip addresses IPv4 and IPv6 from 86.120.51.222 to 1450718174. Currently trying to build the query but don't know much sql

TABLE ip_city_country_location

```
+----+---------+---------------+-------------+
| ID | ip_from |     ip_to     |    city     |
+----+---------+---------------+-------------+
| 1  | 1.2.3.4 | 1.255.255.255 | city_name_1 |
| 2  | 1.3.4.4 | 1.6.0.0       | city_name_2 |
| 3. | 1.0.0.0 | 1.5.5.5       | city_name_3 |
+----+---------+---------------+-------------+
```

What I am thinking on

```
UPDATE ip_city_country_location SET ip_from = INET_ATON(SELECT ip_from FROm ip_city_country_location), ip_to = INET_ATON(SELECT ip_to FROm ip_city_country_location);
```

Notice can also be done with `CASE` and `WHEN` AND `THEN`, but need another a solution that converts automatically because this is a dbs of **5 million rows** and need to run it from shell (xampp). Like to create a function in sql or smth.

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
+----+---------+---------------+-------------+
| ID | ip_from |     ip_to     |    city     |
+----+---------+---------------+-------------+
| 1  | 16909060 | 33554431      | city_name_1 |
| 2  | 16974852 | 17170432      | city_name_2 |
| 3. | 16777216 | 17106181      | city_name_3 |
+----+---------+---------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Why don't you use like this `UPDATE ip_city_country_location 
SET ip_from = INET_ATON(ip_from),
    ip_to = INET_ATON(ip_to);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query you are looking for is pretty straightforward.

Here's the query:

```
UPDATE ip_city_country_location SET ip_from = INET_ATON(ip_from), ip_to = INET_ATON(ip_to);
```

**Note:**

- After converting the ip_addresses to `integer` value you should
  change the datatype to `VARBINARY(16)`.
- Index on `ip_from` and `ip_to` fields would speed up your select
  queries.

**EDIT:**

In order to convert <kbd>[`IPV6`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_is-ipv6)</kbd> addresses you need `MySQL` server version >= `5.6.3`.

And the query would look like below:

```
UPDATE 
ip_city_country_location 
SET ip_from = IF(IS_IPV6(ip_from),INET6_ATON(ip_from), INET_ATON(ip_from)),         
    ip_to = IF(IS_IPV6(ip_to),INET6_ATON(ip_to), INET_ATON(ip_to));
```

**Credit:**
Thanks to @Michael for his valuable comment.

> You cannot store the equivalent of an IPv6 address in an integer
>   column, as IPv6 addresses are 128 bits long, while the longest integer
>   supported by MySQL is BIGINT UNSIGNED, which is only 64 bits.
>   INET6_ATON() returns a VARBINARY(16) for IPv6 addresses.

Comment: What if I have also ipv6 entries, will this work for them too?

Comment: What's the version of your `MySQL`?

Comment: Tried it and it's working for ipv4 but for `2a0a:2f07:ffff:f` they get wiped out. I think it's 5.6.16.

Comment: Look at this [function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_is-ipv6). Supported from mysql version >=5.6.3

Comment: So basically I should do: `IF (IS_IPV6(ip_from) AND IS_IPV6(ip_to))
    UPDATE ip_city_country_location SET ip_from = INET6_ATON(ip_from), ip_to = INET6_ATON(ip_to);
ELSE
    UPDATE ip_city_country_location SET ip_from = INET_ATON(ip_from), ip_to = INET_ATON(ip_to);`

Comment: Yes this is the logic. But you can combine these two logic into a single query. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Ok worked well on a single query just that ipv6 got transformmed in some odd chars LIKE THIS `& UÙ`

Comment: And I do have mysql server version bigger than 5.6.3.

Comment: the documentation says the function was added in mysql version 5.6.3

Comment: You cannot store the equivalent of an IPv6 address in an integer column, as IPv6 addresses are 128 bits long, while the longest integer supported by MySQL is `BIGINT UNSIGNED`, which is only 64 bits.  [`INET6_ATON()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-aton) returns a `VARBINARY(16)` for IPv6 addresses.

Comment: good point. missed that. so `varbinary` should be the right choice, right?  @Michael

Comment: Correct, `VARBINARY(16)` should do it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot , Thanks for your effort. I appreciate that.